# How to make select query dynamically according to selected checbox in php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working on filter, with php(codeigniter). I have three checkboxes, and I want to search(select query), according to selected checkboxes.

If I fill `Type` and `male`, then the query should should look like:

`"Select * from tableName where column1='type' and column='gender'"`

This should occur dynamically, according to the checkbox selected.

How can I do this using Php ?

Here are my html fields

```
<input type="checbox" name="type" value="type">
<input type="checbox" name="male" value="male">
<input type="checbox" name="male" value="male">
```

Comment: you can put codeigniter `where` in condition

Answer (score 0):

You have to try something like this

```
if (isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)) {
  $where = array();
  if ($_POST['type'] != "") {
      $where['type like'] = $this->input->post('type', TRUE);
  }
  if ($_POST['male'] != "") {
      $where['male like'] = $this->input->post('male', TRUE);
  }
}
$data = $this->model->retrieve($where);
```

Comment: if i post only single value(parameter) then ? in other words my query should work according to parameter which i selected for search/filter

Comment: check my updated answer. you want something like this?